# Lower monitor resolution causes tkinter window to be cut at right

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Tkinter gui, and at my default screen resolution (1920x1080), the dashboard displays fine as in image:
[image]

But when I run the same code on a lower resolution laptop (let's say 1366x768), right most widgets are cut as seen in picture below:

[image]

Here is my code which involves 2 windows root_tk is the main window which have a button called dashboard. When we press dashboard button, the dashboard window pops up. I have already tried the solutions [Resolution problem of widgets with fixed lengths in Tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63262780/resolution-problem-of-widgets-with-fixed-lengths-in-tkinter-application)
[Why is my tkinter Gui cut off on the right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68306122/why-is-my-tkinter-gui-cut-off-on-the-right)

But they do not work for me. Here is my code:

```
root_tk = customtkinter.CTk()
root_tk.state("zoomed")
root_tk.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
root_tk.title("CustomTkinter Test")
frame_0 = Frame(root_tk,background="white")
frame_0.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="ns",rowspan=4)

def dash():

    dash_tk2 = customtkinter.CTkToplevel(root_tk)
    dash_tk2.state("zoomed")
    dash_tk2.update_idletasks()
    dash_tk2.title("Dashboard")
    dash_tk2.configure(bg='#302E2E')

    frame_dash1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=dash_tk2, corner_radius=15, fg_color="white")
    frame_dash2 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=dash_tk2, corner_radius=15, fg_color="white")
    frame_dash2a = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=frame_dash2, corner_radius=15, fg_color="#FBBDBE")
    frame_dash3 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=dash_tk2, corner_radius=15, fg_color="white")
    frame_dash3a = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=frame_dash3, corner_radius=15, fg_color="#FBBDBE")
    frame_dash4 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=dash_tk2, corner_radius=15, fg_color="white")
    frame_dash4a = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=frame_dash4, corner_radius=15, fg_color="#FBBDBE")
    frame_dash5 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=dash_tk2, corner_radius=15, fg_color="white")
    frame_dash5a = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=frame_dash5, corner_radius=15, fg_color="#FBBDBE")
    frame_dash6 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=dash_tk2, corner_radius=15, fg_color="white")
    blank_row1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=dash_tk2, fg_color="yellow", height=10)
    blank_col1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=dash_tk2, fg_color="yellow", width=10)
    blank_col2 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=dash_tk2, fg_color="yellow", width=10)
    blank_col3 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=dash_tk2, fg_color="yellow", width=10)
    blank_col4 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=dash_tk2, fg_color="yellow", width=10)
    blank_col5 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=dash_tk2, fg_color="yellow", width=10)
    blank_col6 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=dash_tk2, fg_color="yellow", width=10)
    blank_row1.grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=6)
    blank_col1.grid(row=1, column=0)
    frame_dash1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns',rowspan=2)
    blank_col2.grid(row=1, column=2)
    frame_dash2.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='n',rowspan=2)
    blank_col3.grid(row=1, column=4)
    frame_dash3.grid(row=1, column=5, sticky='n',rowspan=2)
    blank_col4.grid(row=1, column=6)
    frame_dash4.grid(row=1, column=7, sticky='n',rowspan=2)
    blank_col5.grid(row=1, column=8)
    frame_dash5.grid(row=1, column=9, sticky='n',rowspan=2)
    blank_col6.grid(row=1, column=10)
    frame_dash6.grid(row=1, column=11, sticky='n')

    frame_dash2a.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=(20, 10))
    frame_dash3a.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=(20, 10))
    frame_dash4a.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=(20, 10))
    frame_dash5a.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=(20, 10))

    blank_row2 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=frame_dash1, fg_color="orange", height=15)
    blank_row2.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)
    lab_tag = Label(frame_dash1, text="TAG", anchor=W, width=20, font='Tahoma 7', fg="black", bg='white')
    lab_tag2 = Label(frame_dash1, text="FLOW Meter 4981", anchor=W, width=20, font='Tahoma 15', fg="black", bg='white')
    blank_col7 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=frame_dash1, fg_color="orange", width=15)
    blank_col7.grid(row=1, column=0,rowspan=15,sticky='ns')
    lab_tag.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=(10, 0), sticky='w')
    lab_tag2.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='w')

    lab_dashhead2 = Label(frame_dash2, text="MASS FLOW (KG/HR)", anchor=CENTER, font='Tahoma 10 bold', fg="white",bg='#EB3F3F')
    lab_massflow2a = Label(frame_dash2a, text="19,999.999", anchor=CENTER, font='Tahoma 25 bold', fg="black", bg='#FBBDBE',width=10)
    blank_col8 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=frame_dash2, fg_color="orange", width=10)
    blank_col8.grid(row=1, column=0,rowspan=3)
    blank_col9 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=frame_dash2, fg_color="orange", width=10)
    blank_col9.grid(row=1, column=2,rowspan=3)
    lab_dashhead2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew', pady=15, ipady=5, columnspan=3)
    lab_massflow2a.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20)

    lab_dashhead3 = Label(frame_dash3, text="VOLUMETRIC FLOW (M\u00b3/HR)", anchor=CENTER, font='Tahoma 10 bold', fg="white",bg='#EB3F3F')
    lab_massflow3a = Label(frame_dash3a, text="99,999", anchor=CENTER, font='Tahoma 25 bold', fg="black", bg='#FBBDBE',width=10)
    blank_col10 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=frame_dash3, fg_color="orange", width=10)
    blank_col10.grid(row=1, column=0,rowspan=3)
    blank_col11 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=frame_dash3, fg_color="orange", width=10)
    blank_col11.grid(row=1, column=2,rowspan=3)
    lab_dashhead3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew', pady=15, ipady=5, columnspan=3)
    lab_massflow3a.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20)

    lab_dashhead4 = Label(frame_dash4, text="STD.VOLUMETRIC FLOW (KG/HR)", anchor=CENTER, font='Tahoma 10 bold',fg="white", bg='#EB3F3F')
    lab_massflow4a = Label(frame_dash4a, text="99999.99", anchor=CENTER, font='Tahoma 25 bold', fg="black", bg='#FBBDBE',width=10)
    blank_col12 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=frame_dash4, fg_color="orange", width=10)
    blank_col12.grid(row=1, column=0,rowspan=3)
    blank_col13 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=frame_dash4, fg_color="orange", width=10)
    blank_col13.grid(row=1, column=2,rowspan=3)
    lab_dashhead4.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew', pady=15, ipady=5, columnspan=3)
    lab_massflow4a.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20)

    lab_dashhead5 = Label(frame_dash5, text="ENERGY FLOW (KG/HR)", anchor=CENTER, font='Tahoma 10 bold', fg="white",
                          bg='#EB3F3F')
    lab_massflow5a = Label(frame_dash5a, text="99999.99", anchor=CENTER, font='Tahoma 25 bold', fg="black", bg='#FBBDBE',width=10)


    blank_col14 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=frame_dash5, fg_color="orange", width=10)
    blank_col14.grid(row=1, column=0,rowspan=3)
    blank_col15 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=frame_dash5, fg_color="orange", width=10)
    blank_col15.grid(row=1, column=2,rowspan=3)
    lab_dashhead5.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew', pady=15, ipady=5, columnspan=3)
    lab_massflow5a.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20)

    lab_dashhead6a = Label(frame_dash6, text="REAL FACTORS", anchor=CENTER, font='Tahoma 10 bold',fg="white", bg='#7F7F7F',width=34)
    lab_diffpx_un = Label(frame_dash6, text="MEASUREMENT FACTORS INVOLVED IN PROCESS (%)", anchor=CENTER,font='Tahoma 10', fg="black", bg='#C0C0C0',wraplength=200)
    lab_diffpx_un_val = Label(frame_dash6, text="", anchor=CENTER, font='Tahoma 13 bold', fg="black",bg='#E8E8E8')
    lab_dashhead6a.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew', pady=(15,25), ipady=5)
    lab_diffpx_un.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
    lab_diffpx_un_val.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='ew')

    dash_tk2.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use different font size on those numbers based on the screen width.

Answer (score 1):

Good Question! You can actually make a parent frame for all those frames and widgets and add a scrollbar in x axis to that parent frame.. [How to insert a scrollbar to a frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188420/tkinter-scrollbar-for-frame)

Comment: Cant it be done without a scroll bar? Theres gotta be a way of doing this!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a weight to the grid cells you created. If you want every grid cell in row 1 of the top-level to be equally weighted, you do it like the following:

```py
dash_tk2.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), weight=1)
```

Small window:
[image]
Wide window:
[image]